# user_session_ttl hidden variable option not working

Tags: sessions

I have set this hidden variable in my config/config.php file

```
// Allows changing of the Users Session Length to any number in seconds. For instance, if users should be logged out after 10 minutes of inactivity, the value would be: 600
// 30 minutes(60 seconds * 30 )
$config['user_session_ttl'] = 1800;
```

However, it is not working. I tried leaving a page inactive and checking it after an hour many times. But I still don't get logged out.

Any idea why this is the case?

P.S. I am using Safecracker and Safecracker Registration for my Member system. I am using EE 2.5.5 with no immediate plans to upgrade.

UPDATE:

I found out that `user_session_ttl` affects my admin session(logged in via localhost/system) while the session logged in via Safecracker was not affected.

I also found another hidden variable, `cp_session_ttl`. Is this relevant?

Comment: Try by having like this `$config['user_session_ttl'] = "1800";`

Comment: I tried enclosing it in double quotes and changing the value to just 1 to test if it really is logging out. It didn't work.

Comment: Added an observation.

Comment: I would suggest you to see this extension also http://johndwells.com/software/stay-up-forever In this, you can set the user session time from extension settings.

Comment: @BhashkarYadav I tried following your link. But I only saw an error page.

Comment: Can you share that error message also. I hope, someone should help for it. This addon seems to fit for your need.

Comment: There was an EE error earlier. Now, I can't actually connect the page at all.

Comment: I tried the extension. It also did not work. It seems that the both hidden variables are not working at all. Btw, I am using 2.5.5 with no immediate plans to upgrade.

Comment: Any updates to this?